# Julia : How to use "include" function on 2 modules each other?

Tags: include, julia, lang

I'm a beginner in JuliaLang.

I can't understand a thing : how to use "include" function on 2 modules ?

I have [two julia code files (modules)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klg7X.png)

**main.jl** code file

```
module main
    include("xmd.jl") # Here i include 
    a = "Hey, i'm a !"
    println(xmd.b)
end
```

**xmd.jl code file**

```
module xmd
    include("main.jl")
    b = "Hey, i'm b !"
    println(main.a)
end
```

***When I try to compile the main.jl code file (on the same directory as xmd.jl), I get an error***

```
LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: StackOverflowError:
Stacktrace:
 [1] exec at ./pcre.jl:133 [inlined]
 [2] match(::Regex, ::String, ::Int64, ::UInt32) at ./regex.jl:197
 [3] match at ./regex.jl:195 [inlined]
 [4] match at ./regex.jl:210 [inlined]
 [5] splitdir(::String) at ./path.jl:132
 [6] dirname(::String) at ./path.jl:151
 [7] _include_dependency(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:738
 [8] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1030
 [9] include at ./sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
 [10] include(::String) at /home/lazen/Bureau/Lazen-dev/tests/main.jl:1
 [11] top-level scope at none:0
 [12] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [13] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [14] include at ./sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
 [15] include(::String) at /home/lazen/Bureau/Lazen-dev/tests/tests.jl:1
 [16] top-level scope at none:0
 [17] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [18] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 ... (the last 10 lines are repeated 1034 more times)
 [10359] include at ./sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
 [10360] include(::String) at /home/lazen/Bureau/Lazen-dev/tests/main.jl:1
 [10361] top-level scope at none:0
 [10362] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [10363] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [10364] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [10365] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:229
in expression starting at /home/lazen/Bureau/Lazen-dev/tests/main.jl:2
in expression starting at /home/lazen/Bureau/Lazen-dev/tests/tests.jl:2
in expression starting at /home/lazen/Bureau/Lazen-dev/tests/main.jl:2
```

I'm struggling since almost 2 days for this bug. I don't know where it comes from. Does it means I can't include a module on another module if it's vice-versa ?

**Thanks**

Comment: main.jl tries to include xmd.jl and xmd.jl tries to include main.jl which I believe tries to keep on going forever, giving an error as expected. This is not an appropriate pattern for Modules.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.